# hotkey for System.out::println for java8 in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a hotkey for `System.out::println` for java8 like `sout` for `System.out.println()`?

If not, how to create a hotkey for `System.out::println` for java8 in intelliJ?

Comment: I don't think it exists a hotkey for `System.out::println`. Follow the [JetBrains doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) to create it yourself...

Answer (score 3):

It is very common to try to add some `hotkeys` to make our development faster. IntelliJ provides us with this configuration through **templates**.

To do that you can go to `Preferences > Editor > Live Templates` choose `output` and click on `+` button and input the following configuration:

- Abbreviation: `sout8`
- Description: `Prints in Java 8`
- Template text: `System.out::println`
- Applicable in: `Java: statement, expression`

Click on `Apply` and `OK` buttons.

So, when you're writing code, you will can use the hotkey `sout8` only within sentences and expressions, you can modify this behavior in the option `Applicable in`

[image]

Comment: Indeed, very helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct and additionally, you need to define the use case i.e. `Application in Java: statement, expression`

[image]

Now, you should be good to go

[image]